# Can anyone tell me why my code doesn't work properly? Game ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS. Java Script

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why my code doesn't work properly? I'm trying to make game ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS on plain Java Script. For some reason it doesn't work as I expect.

```js
const computerAanswer = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

function computerPlay() {
    let answer = computerAanswer[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerAanswer.length)];
    return answer;
}

console.log('computer choice is: ' + computerPlay().toUpperCase());



function playRound (playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    playerSelection  = playerSelection.toLowerCase()
    
    if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
        return "Congrats,you are winner!";
    }   else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock") {
        return "Congrats,you are winner!";
    }   else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") {
        return "Congrats,you are winner!";
    }   else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "rock") {
        return "Draw!";
    }   else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "paper") {
        return "Draw!";
    }   else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
        return "Draw!";
    }   else {
        return "You lose. Maybe next time...";
    }
}

let playerSelection = prompt("Make your choose: Rock, Paper or Scissors?");
let computerSelection = computerPlay();
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));

console.log('player choice is: ' + playerSelection.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: It would help if you provided an example of what isn't working correctly? I ran it a few times and it seemed to work for me. Also, INB4 someone says "Just return 50/50"

Comment: For example if I input scissors and computer choice is scissors too program can displayed "You lose. Maybe next time..." but expected result is "Draw!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's just your first console.log :

```
console.log('computer choice is: ' + computerPlay().toUpperCase());
```

It plays a round for computer, then you play another one against prompted user.

Do that instead :

```
function computerPlay() {
    let answer = computerAanswer[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerAanswer.length)];
    console.log('computer choice is: ' + answer.toUpperCase()); 
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is at least part of what OP is dealing with. The console log is inaccurate since he calls it again later on, like you point out

Comment: console.log(anyFunction()) === bad idea;

Answer (score 0):

When I nested

```
console.log('computer choice is: ' + answer.toUpperCase());
```

*into computerPlay function* it works.

```
const computerAanswer = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

function computerPlay() {
    let answer = computerAanswer[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerAanswer.length)];
    console.log('computer choice is: ' + answer.toUpperCase()); 
    return answer;
}



function playRound (playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    playerSelection  = playerSelection.toLowerCase()
    
    if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
        return "Congrats,you are winner!";
    }   else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock") {
        return "Congrats,you are winner!";
    }   else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") {
        return "Congrats,you are winner!";
    }   else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "rock") {
        return "Draw!";
    }   else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "paper") {
        return "Draw!";
    }   else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
        return "Draw!";
    }   else {
        return "You lose. Maybe next time...";
    }
}

let playerSelection = prompt("Make your choose: Rock, Paper or Scissors?");
let computerSelection = computerPlay();
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));

console.log('player choice is: ' + playerSelection.toUpperCase());
```